# JMX connection to Springboot get connection refused

Tags: spring-boot, jmx

I am using springboot's sample project from: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot#run-the-application. This is the command I used to run the built jar file:

```
java -jar build/libs/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar - 
Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -
Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12348 -
Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -
Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -
Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=12348 -
Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.7.119
```

Then I tried to use `jmxterm` to connect:
`java -jar ~/Downloads/jmxterm.jar -l localhost:12348`

But getting connection refused error.

Answer (score 0):

The -Dcom.sun... arguments must come *before* the -jar thing.jar . Anything after the -jar thing.jar are considered arguments to your application, and are passed into main.

Answer (score 0):

You have extra chars between hyphen(-) and D.